# multiple JOINS on SAKILA database SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i am taking a SQL course (MYSQL) and I've been asked the following question:
*"In Sakila, every staff member has a home address and is assigned to a store. Stores have address
too. Write a single SELECT query that returns the first name, last name and city name for every
staff member whose home address (staff.address_id) and store address
(store.address_id) are in the same city.
Hints:

- You’ll need at least 4 joins to get it right.
- The result will list 2 staff members."*

I thought I made it with 3 JOINS using this query :

```
use sakila;

select distinct first_name, last_name, city
from city 
join address on city.city_id = address.city_id
join staff on staff.address_id = address.address_id
join store ;
```

but than I was told that the query is incomplete even though the output is correct( if there were more rows in staff table they  would still appear in the output - my query ignores the stores' addresses).
here's my output: [my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj2pg.png)

could you help my out here guys?
thank you so much!

Comment: ANSI SQL has an ON for _each_ JOIN. However, MySQL does things in its own way, again.

Comment: The base is staff member (`staff` table). All another tables must be joined to it. You must join `address` and join `store` which have its own address, independent from member's address, so another independent `address` table's copy must be joined to `store`.

Comment: @jarlh Ah, not using MYSql regularly I didn't actually know that - that strikes me as, along with its ability to disregard proper grouping, pretty poor for newbies particularly for learning poor skills.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT staff.first_name, staff.last_name, city.city
FROM staff                                                       -- staff member
JOIN address address1 ON staff.address_id = address1.address_id  -- member's address
JOIN store ON staff.store_id= store.store_id                     -- members' store
JOIN address address2 ON store.address_id = address2.address_id  -- store's address
JOIN city ON address1.city_id = city.city_id                     -- member's city (may join to address2 and get store's city)
WHERE address1.city_id = address2.city_id                        -- check that member's city and store's city is the same city
```

> | first_name | last_name | city |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Mike | Hillyer | Lethbridge |
> | Jon | Stephens | Woodridge |

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&sample=sakila&fiddle=bb4292dc30784ffbdc547e1daa1bf03c

Comment: wow thank you so much! Last question, isnt this clause ON staff.store_id= store.store_id   mean that the staff member has to work in the store he shares city with?

Comment: @Jov No... why "to work"? none relation sets this.

Comment: I thought so because you set them together by store id so if one employee lives in woodridge but is assigned to the lethbridge store it won’t show.
As I was saying, I’m very new to this language so you’re probably right. Anyway, thank you very much!